# What properties affect the color of item?

Tags: visible-light, atoms, frequency

I already understand how gap bands work and how atoms can absorb/reflect light.  I also already understand that rough objects will reflect light differently in comparison to smooth objects, but I do not understand how things like atomic arrangement affects the color of an object.

Comment: Atomic structure? Are you asking about x-ray illumination now? Or are you interested in birefringent materials?

Comment: Oh, I meant atomic arrangement, sorry.

Comment: Crystal structure matters mostly to x-ray diffraction and optical properties like birefringence. I think you need to formulate a clear question. What you are asking is mostly irrelevant to what you may reasonably want to know.

Comment: You mean "band gaps"? Anyway it is precisely the exact arrangement of the atoms that determines the energy levels of the particle assemble and hence the wavelengths that it can emit after excitation. So it's going to be a long complicated story to account for all the ways colour comes about.

Comment: Even the direction of emission is also constrained by the atomic structure, as in interference patterns. You may want to look at http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/ligcon.html#c1, and also read up on infrared spectroscopy and nuclear magnetic resonance spectroscopy. Don't forget that human perception of colour is also not just a Fourier transform that lets us perceive intensities of wavelengths, so you may be interested in things like the human colour space and colour constancy.